# Can't play video file

Tags: iphone, video, movie

I'm probably missing something really obvious.

I've included `<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` and have this code:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToFile];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mediaPlayer];
mediaPlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[mediaPlayer release];
```

But the video won't play. I copied the code from another place where the video works perfectly.

`pathToFile` is correct becuase the variable is used in previous lines to move the video from the resources folder to the documents directory.

Any ideas why it might not be working?

Thanks

Comment: double check that it is where you think it is. has the copy completed, for instance?

Comment: `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path]`

Comment: Also, does it play from the resource directory, but not the documents directory? What happens when this code runs...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code except to  presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated

```
NSString *movieFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
moviePlayer= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

this works fine for me.

Comment: This works, but the ViewController one doesn't work! :( I found I had to make the view controller I was working in into a navigation controller in order for it to work. No idea why, the apple reference on this says `This method is part of a category on the UIViewController class and is implemented by the Media Player framework.` Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` retains its receiver, so it looks as though you're releasing your movie player too early. You could try making mediaPlayer a retained property:

```
@interface MyClass : SuperClass {
    MVMoviePlayerViewController *mediaPlayer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) MVMoviePlayerViewController *mediaPlayer;
@end

@implementation MyClass 
@synthesize mediaPlayer;
// rest of class implementation here...
@end
```

Then initialise as so:

```
self.mediaPlayer = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
                    initWithContentURL:videoURL] autorelease];
```

And release afterwards with:

```
self.mediaPlayer = nil;
```

(To write code that happens after the video has finished playing, check out the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification.)

Also bear in mind that `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` first appeared in iOS 3.2, so this code won't work on earlier iOS versions. But I don't think that's the problem in this case.